# Hibernate - find entities, which has another entity inside set

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have two classes: EventEntity and InterestEntity. EventEntity has a Set of InterestEntity. My problem is, how to find only EventEntities with given InterestEntity inside them. How can I implement it in my EventRepository class?

**My EventEntity class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENTS")
public class EventEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "events")
    private Set<InterestEntity> interests;
    
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**My InterestEntity class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INTERESTS")
public class InterestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "events_interests",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "interest_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "event_id")})
    private Set<EventEntity> events;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:**

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<EventEntity, Long> {

    List<EventEntity> findByInterestsContains(InterestEntity interestEntity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JpaRepository will not "understand" the findByInterestsContains method, so you need to create your own implementation of your EventRepository interface. In order to use the Jpa Query methods you need to check the documentation rules https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 0):

You can try like if you want to find Interest Id

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<EventEntity, Long> {

    List<EventEntity> findByInterestsIdIn(List<Long> ids);
}
```

If you are looking at the specific id then it would be like

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<EventEntity, Long> {

    List<EventEntity> findByInterestsId(Long id);
}
```

Comment: But if I want to search only by one InterestEntity, could it be:

`List<EventEntity> findByInterestsIdIn(Long interestId);`

?

Comment: @Vicardo Then it would be List<EventEntity> findByInterestsId(Long id);

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. No entries found.

Comment: What SQL does it generate?

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<EventEntity, Long> {

    @Query("select e from EventEntity e join e.interests i where i.id=:id group by e")
    List<EventEntity> findByInterestsId(Long id);
}
```